# Converting Swift to F# - optionals and type casting

Tags: ios, swift, f#, option-type

I'm trying to convert the following `Swift` code into `F#`:

```
if let type : String = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "type") as? String {
    if (type == "this") {

    } else if (type == "that") {

    }
}
```

I came up with this, however I'm not sure how to cast the value to a `String` and store it in a variable, as all this code does is checks if the value is not null.

```
if NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.ValueForKey(new NSString("type")) <> null then printf("fofo")
```

Comment: I don't know F# so I can't help with your specific question, but I can tell you that `object(forKey:)` and `valueForKey(_:)` are not the same thing. The method `object(forKey:)` is an instance method of UserDefaults/NSUserDefaults. The method `valueForKey(_:)` is a KVC method.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a objectforkey method in F# though

Comment: @Alk There is a specific method to retrieve String values from UserDefaults called `string(forKey:)`. You can also use the nil coalescing operator  `??` to assign a default value or an empty string in case the there is no value assigned yet. `let type = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "type") ?? "default string"`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks, but would this work in F#...my swift code works, I'm more worried about converting it to F# now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In F#, you can do casting using either the `:>` operator (if the cast is an upcast) or the `:?>` operator if the cast is a downcast.  It would look something like this:

```
let objObject= "test" :> obj
let strObject = objObject:?> string;;

val objObject: obj = "test"
val strObject : string = "test"
```

Converting your use defaults would look something like this:

```
let strValue = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.ValueForKey(new NSString("type")) :?> string
```

If you want to check for multiple types, then you'll probably want to use pattern matching like this:

```
let strObject = match objObject with
                | :? string as strObject -> strObject
                | :? System.Int32 as intObject -> ""
```